# Are coarse spaces of 1-dimensional smooth proper Artin stacks smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a regular proper 1-dimensional Artin stack with finite diagonal, with coarse space morphism $\mathcal{X} \to X$.

**Question**: Is $X$ regular?

Some comments:

1. I'm happy to assume that $\mathcal{X} \to X$ is birational.
2. I'm happy to assume that $\mathcal{X}$ is over a field and to replace regular with smooth. (But I am also interested in the case where $X$ is Spec of a Dedekind domain.
3. If $\mathcal{X}$ is additionally a Deligne-Mumford stack, or tame, then $X$ is smooth.
4. Jack Hall pointed out to me that we can weaken tameness a bit: it is enough to assume that $\mathcal{X} \to X$ is an adequate moduli space, in the sense of Alper.

Answer (score 3):

Jack Hall pointed out to me over email that a stack with a coarse space is adequate, so this does it.